# How to tell if a program is installed on Linux in Haskell

Tags: bash, haskell, posix

I'm creating a script that uses an external program that interacts with a server.
I want to test first that the program is installed before trying to use it.

I looked up the preferred way to tell if a program was installed and found this post:
[How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

TLDR: It recommends "command -v <prog-name>" over "which <prog-name>" since it is POSIX compatible. The command should return 0 if the program was found, >0 otherwise.

So I used `readProcessWithExitCode` from System.Process as follows

```
readProcessWithExitCode "command" ["-v", "<some-program>"] ""
```

I get the following error when testing in GHCI

Exception: command: readCreateProcessWithExitCode: posix_spawnp: does not exist (No such file or directory)

I tried to use 'which' on 'command'. It tells me it does not exist although I can use it and it works as described in the man pages in my terminal.

What's going on here and how do I see if something is installed using Haskell?

Some system information:

- GHC: 9.0.2
- resolver: lts-19.11
- "I use Arch btw"

Comment: `command` is a _shell_ builtin, not a program. And it will also ok other built-in commands (including `command -v command`), so not really suitable. I'd say `which` _is_ the better choice for what you want. And it also allows you to look at the actual path and decide whether that's suitable.

Comment: Alright. @leftaroundabout Should what you have be an answer?

Comment: No, because I'm not confident to recommend `which` – there _are_ certainly some things that can go wrong with it, and likely there's a better solution with something from the `unix` package.

Comment: Document that your script requires `<prog-name>` to work correctly, and let the caller ensure that it is installed correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that you simply run the program you want to run, and catch the exception you get if it isn't available. Like this:

```
catch
    (callProcess "lol-this-does-not-exist" []) -- or whatever
    (\e -> if isDoesNotExistError e then putStrLn "yikes" else throw e)
```

Comment: Probably should use something like `--version` as the argument.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I disagree completely. Simply run the command you actually want to run. If what you really wanted was to run `mpv my-fair-lady.mp3`, then run `mpv my-fair-lady.mp3`, not `mpv --version`.

Comment: @DainelWagner This makes sense, is it better to use callProcess or readProcessWithExitCode? I figured the latter is better since it provides the error code.

Comment: @VilePoison I'm not tied to `callProcess`; I used it only because it was the simplest one that I could use to demonstrate my point. (Hence the `or whatever` comment -- use the function that's best for your needs.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh I see. I'm not an expert with process calling in general. I was just curious if `callProcess` has unique executions for each exit code. Thanks for the help